# jScrollPane working only first time with AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a div (`#grouped_tests`) being populated via ajax.  I am then assigning jScrollPane to that div on data load.  However, `jscrollpane` only works the first time that `.group_test` is clicked, not on subsequent clicks.  What do I need to add to get jScrollPane working each time `.group_test` is clicked?

```
 $('.group_test').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/get_grouped_tests.php",
                    data: {
                        group_test: $(this).attr('data-grouptest')
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#grouped_tests').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
                        $('#grouped_tests').jScrollPane({
                            autoReinitialise: true,
                            verticalDragMinHeight: 20,
                            verticalDragMaxHeight: 20
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out from the jScrollPane documentation at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html.  I needed to add:

```
$('#grouped_tests').jScrollPane().data().jsp.destroy();
```

This clears the instance of jScrollPane so that it can be reintialised on data load:

```
 $('.group_test').click(function() {
                $('#grouped_tests').jScrollPane().data().jsp.destroy();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/get_grouped_tests.php",
                    data: {
                        group_test: $(this).attr('data-grouptest')
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#grouped_tests').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
                        $('#grouped_tests').jScrollPane({
                            autoReinitialise: true,
                            verticalDragMinHeight: 20,
                            verticalDragMaxHeight: 20
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```